# ngx-uploader: TS2339: Property 'lastModifiedDate' does not exist on type 'File'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli, ngx-uploader

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/ngx-uploader/src/ngx-uploader/classes/ngx-uploader.class.ts(112,32):
>   error TS2339: Property 'lastModifiedDate' does not exist on type
>   'File'.

I'm getting this error while I was upgrading my angular app from version 5.2 to version 8.
I believe it's because the newer version of typescript has deprecated this field in favor of the new field introduced, `lastModified`.

Is there any way I can overcome this error without depending on the library to get updated?

My current **app configuration** is:

```
Angular: 8.1.1
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Answer (score 0):

install latest version of ngx-uploader.
npm install ngx-uploader@latest